# getelementbyid not working and returning null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with the `getElementById` in javascript, the console just says 'cannot read property 'style' of null, i.e the element is null, even though it is not null?

html

```
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: I think you are trying to access before DOM gets loaded.

Comment: how do i execute the code after the dom gets loaded?

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: If element is dynamic, browser does that sometimes. SO, we have to apply operation on element on body load or document load.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: thank you slacker, i've moved my script to the bottom of the html document, and by the looks of things it seems to have worked! thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
```

See it's working..

Comment: Annoyingly it's not working for me on brackets, I am using chrome to run the code and it's not working. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: check the length of that element first. if it's 0 OR 1 and keep the JS inside  document.load

Answer (score 0):

are you tying to set the color of the h1 before the dom is loaded? try this:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

function myFunction(){
     document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'red';
}
```